# Coincidence Tyrion told Pycelle that Myrcella was going to Dorne ( and then she actually did)?

Tags: game-of-thrones

In Season 2, in order to discover who was leaking information to Cersei, Tyrion told Pycelle, Baelish, and Varys that Myrcella would be married away to different houses.

Tyrion told Pycelle she would marry into `House Martell`.
Tyrion told Varys she would marry into `the Iron Born`.
Tyrion told Baelish she shoud would marry into `the Vale`.

In the end, Myrcella was to be married into House Martell. And, Pycelle turned out to be the leak.

This had to just be a coincidence, right? Or, did Tyrion suspect something and knew she was going to House Martell?

Comment: I think it's just that there are only so many truly advantageous marriage options  for a princess, and each false rumor had to be believable...thus it makes sense that when she actually was sent away, it would be to shore up relations with one of those important houses

Comment: Myrcella was not to be married off to house Martell, was she. She was there to be fostered, IIRC. Same as why Ned and Robert grew up in the Eyrie.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tyrion made the decision to send Myrcella to Dorne based on what was leaked to Cersei.

Conversation between Tyrion and Varys in A Clash of Kings:

> (Tyrion)“What Cersei does not know will never hurt me.” (Varys) “And if Her Grace were to discover your intentions before your plans are ripe?” (Tyrion)“Why,” he said, “**then I would know the man who told her to be my certain enemy.”**

There were three advantageous marriages available, (Martell, Tyrell and Arryn), and this gave Tyrion the ability to determine who the leak was as well.